# Images (other applications icons) on Android app rendering smaller on hdpi device if android:minSdkVersion="7" is specified

Tags: android, device, hdpi

One of the activity in my apps, displays all the installed apps on the phone in a Grid View. The icons are displayed in the activity as shown in default launcher if the android manifest does not contains uses-sdk tag. 
But if I add (uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>    in the manifest, the icons in HDPI devices (also in emulator) appears smaller than how they are displayed in default launcher screen.

I was able to replicate this behavior in sample app "Home" that comes with android sdk.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!!